# Help with an improper integral!

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals, infinity

I need some help with an indefinite integral problem (only the $2^{\textrm{nd}}$ part though). Problem is as follows. Consider the function $f(x) = \dfrac{\ln\!\left(x\right)}{x^{p}}$, where $p>1$ and $1 \le a \le b$.  
 1. Compute $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$ in terms of $p, a$ and $b$.  
 2. Now compute $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ in terms of $p$ and $a$ by letting $b \to \infty$ in your first answer.

The correct answer to the first one is:

$\dfrac{-\left(b^{1-p}\!\left(1+\left(-1+p\right)\ln\!\left(b\right)\right)\right)}{\left(-1+p\right)^{2}}-\dfrac{-\left(a^{1-p}\!\left(1+\left(-1+p\right)\ln\!\left(a\right)\right)\right)}{\left(-1+p\right)^{2}}$

I only have difficulty in getting the $2^{\textrm{nd}}$ one right. Any ideas?

By letting $b \to \infty$ I get $\lim_{b\to\infty}\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$ and having calculated $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$ I got:  
  
 $\lim_{b\to\infty}(\dfrac{-\left(b^{1-p}\!\left(1+\left(-1+p\right)\ln\!\left(b\right)\right)\right)}{\left(-1+p\right)^{2}}-\dfrac{-\left(a^{1-p}\!\left(1+\left(-1+p\right)\ln\!\left(a\right)\right)\right)}{\left(-1+p\right)^{2}})$  
  
From here i am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out the long way. I must say that it is a bit long but still I was on the right track and the answer was accepted. What I did was I took:  
 $\lim_{b\to\infty}(\dfrac{-\left(b^{1-p}\!\left(1+\left(-1+p\right)\ln\!\left(b\right)\right)\right)}{\left(-1+p\right)^{2}}-\dfrac{-\left(a^{1-p}\!\left(1+\left(-1+p\right)\ln\!\left(a\right)\right)\right)}{\left(-1+p\right)^{2}})$  
Then I continued on with all of the fraction inside of the limit. Expanded it, and got the form:  
 $\dfrac{a^{1-p}}{(p-1)^2}+\dfrac{p a^{1-p} \ln (a)}{(p-1)^2}-\dfrac{a^{1-p} \ln (a)}{(p-1)^2}-\dfrac{b^{1-p}}{(p-1)^2}-\dfrac{p b^{1-p} \ln (b)}{(p-1)^2}+\dfrac{b^{1-p}
\ln (b)}{(p-1)^2}$ 
I took the limit of each one of them:  
$\lim_{b\to\infty}(\dfrac{a^{1-p}}{(p-1)^2}+\dfrac{p a^{1-p} \ln (a)}{(p-1)^2}-\dfrac{a^{1-p} \ln (a)}{(p-1)^2}-\dfrac{b^{1-p}}{(p-1)^2}-\dfrac{p b^{1-p} \ln (b)}{(p-1)^2}+\dfrac{b^{1-p}
\ln (b)}{(p-1)^2})$ 
We can see in the expression that only the last three have a $b$ in their expression and it is those that I evaluated. By evaluated each one of them I noticed that they clear out (meaning they $ = 0$). This leaves us with only the first 3 fractions expressed in terms of $a$ and $p$. That was the correct answer. 
Evaluations: 
1. $\lim_{b\to\infty}(-\dfrac{b^{1-p}}{(p-1)^2})$. In this case since $p>1$ the expression $b^{1-p}$ will have $1-p<0$, consequently, this will make $b^{1-p}$ be part of the denominator. As ${b\to\infty}$ the limit will be of the form $1/\infty$, which in limits is equal to $0$.  
2. $\lim_{b\to\infty}(-\dfrac{p b^{1-p} \ln (b)}{(p-1)^2})$. Same principle as numer 1. The $b^{1-p}$ will go on bottom, in this case making the limit similar to $\lim_{x\to\infty}(\dfrac{ln(x)}{x})$ which is $=0$.  
3. $\lim_{b\to\infty}(\dfrac{b^{1-p}\ln (b)}{(p-1)^2})$ Same analogy with #2. The $b^{1-p}$ will go on bottom, in this case making the limit similar to $\lim_{x\to\infty}(\dfrac{ln(x)}{x})$ which is $=0$. 
Correct Answer: $\dfrac{a^{1-p}}{(p-1)^2}+\dfrac{p a^{1-p} \ln (a)}{(p-1)^2}-\dfrac{a^{1-p} \ln (a)}{(p-1)^2}$
This can can be factored.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: As $p>1$, use L'Hopital's rule one has:

$$\lim_{b\to+\infty}\frac{\ln b}{b^{p-1}}=\lim_{b\to+\infty}\frac{1/b}{(p-1)b^{p-2}}=\lim_{b\to+\infty}\frac{1}{(p-1)b^{p-1}}=0$$

Comment: I posted the answer below (not that much thoroughly explained thou).